# Como desabilitar o AutoCommit no FireDac

Tags: delphi, firedac

Como seria para desabilitar o AutoCommit tipo:

```
FDTable1.AutoCommit := False;
```

ou

```
FDconection.AutoCommit := False;
```

não estou achando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma:

```
FDConnection1.TxOptions.AutoCommit := False;
```

Comment: Vou tentar aqui para ver se fica bem...

Comment: É resolveu o problema e ficou bem rápido para gravar.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que vale destacar que a opção `AutoCommit` simplesmente limpa os UpdateStatus dos registros. 
Diferente do `ApplyUpdates` do `ClientDataSet`, que retornava todos os registros para `usUnModified` automaticamente, o `FDQuery` os mantém. 
Imagino que seja assim para que possamos, após dar um `ApplyUpdates`, fazer novas alterações no banco banco de dados de acordo com o estado do registro.

Assim, se você executar `ApplyUpdates` seguidas vezes (por conta de alguma automação, por exemplo), você poderá obter um erro de chave primária entre outros decorrentes da tentativa de executar duas vezes a mesma operação.